# I made arms and legs in blender and i want to individually postition them but auto mirror wont let me, how to turn auto mirror off?

Tags: blender, mirror

I made the arms of my character using auto mirror, but now i want to postion them individually but it wont let me t urn off auto mirror, how do i do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which one you mean "Mirror modifier" or "Mesh symmetry" in Sculptor mode

Mirror modifier: Click drop down menu and select apply and you can move them separately.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhZy7.png)

Mesh symmetry : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sSwF.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).